# How to open PA chat bot in new window when click on chat button using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, power-virtual-agents

I have integrated my PVA chat bot on portal.but I want it to open in new window when I click on chat bot button.and then we can chat with bot

I am just confused with the **help of button class** how we can achieve it.

I don't have any change url to open in new window..I just wanted to open in new window when I click on button

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what you want, you can use `window.open` then set your link like this:

```
<button class="button" onClick="window.open('your url');">
     Open
</button>
```